# Listing files in a directory - how to prevent directory name being included

Tags: rust

I'm new to Rust and am trying to do a simple task - listing all files in a directory using the [ignore crate](https://docs.rs/ignore/latest/ignore/) to prevent hidden files being listed. The code below works but I'm also getting the name of the directory listed as the first entry - how can I prevent that?

```
use ignore::Walk;
for file in Walk::new("/tmp/foo_directory"){
    match file {
        Ok(entry) => println!("{}", entry.path().display()),
        Err(err) => println!("Error: {}", err),
    }
}
```

This gives me (for example):

```
/tmp/foo_directory  <--- how can this be stopped?
/tmp/foo_directory/file1.txt
/tmp/foo_directory/file2.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see such option, but you can always filter it yourself:

```rust
use ignore::Walk;

fn main() {
    for file in Walk::new(".") {
        match file {
            Ok(entry) if entry.depth() > 0 => {
                println!("{}={}", entry.path().display(), entry.depth())
            }
            Ok(_) => {}
            Err(err) => println!("Error: {}", err),
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Or just `Walk::new (".").skip (1)` since `ignore::Walk` uses `walkdir` internally, which always returns the current folder first by default.

Comment: @Jmb I didn't see it guaranteed in the docs, which is why I didn't want to rely on it.

Comment: Well, [`walkdir` does guarantee it](https://docs.rs/walkdir/latest/walkdir/struct.WalkDir.html#method.contents_first), but you're right, I didn't see it in the `ignore` docs.